# Cargo init creates new dir as like cargo new

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have no idea why this acts the same in both cases

[image]

[image]

Comment: What would you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect cargo init to create all files in current location, without creating new dir instead

Comment: Mb i don't understand how it should work, then can anybody explain it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found answer.

- `cargo init` without args works as expected: creates files in
  current location.
- `cargo init` with args acts like `cargo new`.